# JS Function working as variable [ getEventListeners API ]

Tags: javascript, function

I have two similar functions, but one works and the other not

```
function notWorking(el) {
    return getEventListeners(el);
}
notWorking(document);
// result --> Uncaught ReferenceError: getEventListeners is not defined

working = function(el) {
    return getEventListeners(el);
}
working(document);
// result --> Object {keyup: Array[1], …}
```

Why is getEventListeners working inside the second function and not inside the first?

Comment: Add an example of both code snippets

Comment: Please edit the code, you have some typos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Can you add the function call?

Comment: @Shailendra Sharma: no it's not. It does not explain, why getEventListeners is not working. I understood that a variable is not hoisted up and hence there is a difference, but why is getEventListeners is not working?

Comment: @Tushar: Added an example.

Comment: @VladNeacsu: fixed the typo.

Comment: @Aexis Dufrenoy: added a function call

Comment: what is your desire output

Comment: @Shailendra Sharma: I would like to get the eventlisteners on the element. I added the results to the example.

Comment: what plateform you are using to run that code ?

Comment: there ? please tell me plateform

Comment: @Shailendra Sharma: chrome ver: 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)

Comment: where, and how is getEventListeners declared ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly to all those question comments, `getEventListeners` is not custom method, it is the console api provided by browser.

### [getEventListeners(object)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference#geteventlistenersobject)

> getEventListeners(object) returns the event listeners registered on
>   the specified object.

I executed the code which you have provided in the question. It just works fine in **Firefox**, check the attached snapshot

[image: Firefox firebug]

I executed the same in **Chrome** browser
[image: Chrome devtools]

But this is not expected. As it is **valid** and also Firefox is doing right, the same should have been worked in chrome. I checked all the answers in [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) and all other resources. It explains the scope/visibility of function declaration and function expression. But here  **the problem is visibility of getEventListeners function** not function-working or function-notWorking.

So I think this must be defect in Chrome or the method `getEventListerners` should not be used in script, it is only for debugging purpose as specified in [Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference).

> **Note** : This API is only available from within the console itself. You
>   cannot access the Command Line API from scripts on the page.

---

More information

```
getEventListeners.toString()
> "function getEventListeners(node) { [Command Line API] }"

this.getEventListeners
> undefined          //function is not accessible via window object

// where as

this.setTimeout
> setTimeout() { [native code] }
```